# How To Make Scroll View Scroll Even If A Button Subview Is Pressed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uibutton

There are countless questions about `UIScrollView`s, touch events and subviews, but I couldn't find one that solved my dilemma. I have a `UIScrollView` with delayed and cancellable content touches in which I have added `UIButton`s. I can scroll the view wherever I touch (including the buttons), but if my finger lingers on a button for too long, it registers as touching the button, as I want and is expected. However, if I then move my finger as if trying to scroll, the scroll view does not scroll - how can I make it do so? The basic effect I am trying to achieve is like a `UITableView` handles touches for the cells.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: could you achieve something similar by customising table view cells and then using the built in capabilities of the table view?

Comment: It's a 2d grid with buttons with rounded corners, custom gradient effects and shadows. If you can advise me on how to make it use cells then please post as an answer, but I thought it would be easier to do it via buttons in a scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing the following in your UIScrollView subclass:

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view {   
    return YES;
}
```